# I want to check for multiple words in a string saved in mysql column

Tags: mysql, wildcard, keyword-search

I want to get results saved in MySQL table column based on existence of Keywords.
(WANT TO SELECT * WHERE KEYWORDS EXISTS)

tried changing and to or but not working I want to get matched keywords highlighted too when using OR

```
SELECT * FROM ic_hadith_urdu WHERE title LIKE N'%نشہ%' OR N'%کیا%' LIMIT 20
```

I am using this above SQL query but not working

Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: %keyword%

Comment: Is the `N` in `LIKE N'%نشہ%'` a typo or something?

Comment: Just use: `WHERE title LIKE '%نشہ%' OR title LIKE '%کیا%'`

Comment: without N it does not search for matching arabic letters its some utf8 character set problem previously searched on stack overflow another problem